# Can a data structure object be attached to a textbox for autocompletion

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a textbox which I what to use auto-complete on. For example, if use types the starting characters, a dropdown shows up with options. This what I'm currently doing using the following code:

```
inputTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
inputTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
inputTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = inputStringCollection; //inputStringCollection contains the list of possible strings
```

What I need:

I want to be able to search *multiple types* of data using this text box (e.g Full Name, username, email, phone numbers, etc). For example, a customer has attributes such as his full name, his username in the system, his list of phone numbers, list of emails, etc. Right now, I have separate textboxes for each of these, but I want to merge them all into one. So the idea is that I should be able to search all types of attributes within the same textbox.

The problem:

One possible implementation coming to my mind is to make separate string collections for each type of attribute, then merge them all into one, and then attach that consolidated string collection to this text box. The problem with this approach is that I cannot handle duplicates. Suppose there is a person whose name and username are both 'John'. In such a case, I won't know what type of attribute was selected from the drop down.

The question:

Is it possible to attach something other than a mere string collection to the textbox's auto-completion mechanism ? Maybe I can have an Arraylist storing custom data-structure objects, each of which defines several values such as ID, type of attribute, etc .. Or something similar ? This way when the user selects an entry from the drop down, I can know what type of attribute that was that the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

What normally happens in Software, and this was introduced with the first version of iTunes Store for Mac, is the ability for have only 1 search box that answers for any type of search.

What we, developers, end up doing is making the use of the `case` variable in SQL, or in our dynamic language prior to the database selection.

something within the lines as

- if a `@` char was found in the search, let's find by email addresses
- if a phone number (matched by `regex` for example) was found, let's search by phone numbers
- if an `integer` was found, let's find by order id
- ...
- else, let's find by customer name, address or city

This is how we normally make just one search box be the "Search everything", witch is not really everything, but it's how the search format is that we know where to search.

There's always a good practice to have an "advanced search" where we have all bunch of fields that can really make a dynamic query be powerful, as it's only in special cases that a user would use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly make up your own "String collection" object that externally looks like an ordinary list, but internally keeps all your actual lists inside, then searches all of them when the interface methods are called. You'd need to look into how the auto-complete stuff gets its suggestions.